# Solving for $x$ (a quadratic equation)

Tags: quadratics, absolute-value

> If  $a\le0$, then roots of $x^2$ - $2a$|$x-a$| - $3a^2$ = $0$ are?
>
> (A) $a$
>
> (B) $($$\sqrt{6}$-$1$$)$$a$
>
> (C) $($-$\sqrt{6}$-$1$$)$$a$
>
> (D) None of these

I solved it by considering three cases.

Case-1 : When $x$ $>$ $a$ : In this case, $x$ = $a$ - $\sqrt{2}a$ is the root. (The other root $x$ = $a$ + $\sqrt{2}a$ gets rejected, since $x$ $>$ $a$)

Case-2 : When $x$ $<$ $a$ : In this case, $x$ = $($$\sqrt{6}$$-$$1$$)$$a$ is the root. (The other root $x$ = $($$-\sqrt{6}$$-$$1$$)$$a$ gets rejected since $x$ $<$ $a$)

Case-3 : When $x$= $a$ : In this case, I’m getting $a$ = $0$

The correct answer according to my book is (B).

(B) is indeed correct, but I don’t understand why $a$ = $0$ (Case-3) gets rejected? In that case I assumed that $x$ = $a$, and I got $a$ = $0$, which means $x$ = $a$ = $0$. And putting $x$ = $a$ = $0$ in the given equation reduces the LHS of the original equation to $0$. So $x$ = $a$ = $0$ should be a root too? This is the reason I am posting it. Shouldn’t $x$ = $a$ = $0$ be a root of the given equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $x = a$ is a root, but only for the case where $a = 0$, as you stated. However, note that for $a = 0$, the values of (A), (B) and (C) are also $0$. In particular, this case is already included in the case of $B$, which is possibly what the question had intended. Regardless, I consider it to be at least a misleading, if not also inaccurate, question.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. It irks me when questions contain incomplete information, which is the case with many questions in my book, unfortunately. Hence I've been putting up many posts lately, to clear up my doubts

Comment: @πtimese You're welcome; I'm glad I could help. Even if I'm right about the book intending for (B) to include the case $a = 0$, it should've used different expressions which couldn't be correct for the other answers to avoid this possible confusion.

Comment: Yeah. The way those four options have been given in the book, it seems as if the book has not considered the 3rd case when $x$ = $a$. Even if it has, it looks like it has not, which is what got me confused.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_a(x):=x^2-2a|x-a|-3a^2.$

If $a=0$, then $f_a(x)=f_0(x)=x^2$ , hence $f_a(x)=0 \iff x=0.$

Conclusion: if $a=0$, then $f_a$ has the root $a$, and you are right.

Answer (score 1):

1. If $a \geq 0$, then $a = 0$.
2. If $a=0$, then $x^2-2a|x-a|-3a^2=x^2$.
3. If $x^2-2a|x-a|-3a^2=0$, then $x^2=0$, because $x^2-2a|x-a|-3a^2=x^2$.
4. If $x^2=0$, then $x=0$.